# php get the timestamp of last october

Tags: php, strtotime

Is it possible to get the last october using strtotime ?

eg `strtotime("last October");`

currently im using this but would prefer to use strtotime

`date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,10,1,date("Y") - !(date(m) > 9)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
strtotime(date('Y-10-01') . (date('m') < 10 ? ' -1 year' : ''));
```

Not sure how you want to deal with the case that it is currently october. If you want it to show last october then change the `<` to a `<=`.

Comment: Oh I see that won't work correctly if it is past October. You want the last October not last calendar year October correct?

Comment: Yes, so the last october to have occurred, So in november this year, It it will be october this year, in september this year it will be october last year

Comment: Checks out: https://eval.in/130240. I would say go with `<=`. If it was October 5th and I said, "I dated her last October" you wouldn't think I meant yesterday ;).

Comment: Yeah not sure what the application is for this cause you are still getting just the starting day of the month not the month as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

in strtotime function, for the time argument you need to consider the GNU syntax which are all  applicable. not sure that you can directly use the string "last october" to get the timestamp value.  for more info, refer http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Date-input-formats.html.